# I want to speed up a nested loop when creating a df keyword counts (keywords appearing with other keywords)

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

Using Pandas
I have a df that is 14000 rows by 56 columns (keywords)
I have a keyword list (full_keys) that is 1406 items and an empty (0) dataframe (called key_frame)that uses the keyword list as index and columns (so 1406x1406)

I want to iterate through each row of the df, and for each keyword in the row, increment the intersection in key_frame of that keyword and each other keyword that exists in the row.

```
key_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=full_keys, index=full_keys).fillna(0) # create empty df 

for i, r in keywords.iterrows(): #iterate through each row in df
  for index, rows in key_frame.iterrows(): #iterate through blank df to tabulate
    if index in list(r): # if the index (which is a keyword) appears in row...
      for x in r: #iterate through row and for each intersection loc[index, x] increment tally by 1
        key_frame.loc[index, x]+=1
```

I also have this, same as above but for commented line:

```
key_frame_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=full_keys, index=full_keys).fillna(0)

for i, r in keywords.iterrows():
  for x in full_keys: #iterate through list rather than key_frame, it's...faster?
    if x in list(r):
      for keyword in r:
        key_frame_2.loc[x, keyword]+=1
```

Feeling rusty and would love some pointers! I know there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `keywords` data frame only contains elements from `full_keys`:

```
>>> full_keys = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
>>> keywords
   0  1  2
0  B  A  C
1  C  B  D
2  E  C  D
3  A  D  E
4  E  A  D
```

you can first create a DataFrame that contains, for each row in keywords, a row with a list of all the pairs of keywords in it (including duplicates, and in all orderings). We achieve that using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
key_frame = keywords.apply(lambda row: list(itertools.product(row, repeat=2)), axis=1)
```

```
>>> key_frame
0    [(B, B), (B, A), (B, C), (A, B), (A, A), (A, C...
1    [(C, C), (C, B), (C, D), (B, C), (B, B), (B, D...
2    [(E, E), (E, C), (E, D), (C, E), (C, C), (C, D...
3    [(A, A), (A, D), (A, E), (D, A), (D, D), (D, E...
4    [(E, E), (E, A), (E, D), (A, E), (A, A), (A, D...
dtype: object
```

Then, flatten those lists to get a Series of all pairs, and count the pairs (this basically gives you a one-dimensional histogram of keyword pairs):

```
key_frame = key_frame.explode().value_counts()
```

```
>>> key_frame
(D, D)    4
(A, A)    3
(D, E)    3
...
(C, E)    1
(A, C)    1
(A, B)    1
dtype: int64
```

Now, to turn this into a two-dimensional histogram of keywords, we use [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), which requires that the index be a MultiIndex, instead of an index of tuples:

```
key_frame.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(key_frame.index)
key_frame = key_frame.unstack()
```

```
>>> key_frame
     A    B    C    D    E
A  3.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0
B  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
C  1.0  2.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
D  2.0  1.0  2.0  4.0  3.0
E  2.0  NaN  1.0  3.0  3.0
```

At this stage the `key_frame` DataFrame contains all the non-zero entries in the DataFrame you want. This might already be good enough, but in order to fill in missing columns, rows, or NaN entries, we can use [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
key_frame = key_frame.reindex(full_keys, columns=full_keys).fillna(0)
```

```
>>> key_frame
     A    B    C    D    E
A  3.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0
B  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  0.0
C  1.0  2.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
D  2.0  1.0  2.0  4.0  3.0
E  2.0  0.0  1.0  3.0  3.0
```

Which should give you a DataFrame identical to one achieved using your code, but at a fraction of the time - running your code took around 100x time than this solution on the same `keywords` DataFrame (with 100 rows and 10 columns).

Comment: This is a massive ram hog.  The file I am using looks like:

len(full_keys) = 1938

keywords.shape = (1518, 108)